# Spring WebFlux with MongoDB - throttling SSE clients

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-mongodb, reactor-netty

I am working on a simple chat service ran by Spring Boot 2.1.1 with WebFlux, Reactor 3.2.3, Mongo 3.8.2 and Netty 4.1.31.

Each chat room has 2 collections - messages archive and a capped collection with current events (eg. new message event, user typing indicators etc.). The capped collection has 100 elements and I am using tail() method of ReactiveMongoTemplate to retrieve latest events.

The service exposes 2 kinds of endpoints for retrieving the recent events: SSE and for polling. I have done some stress testing with 2000 concurrent users which apart from listening to the chat, were spamming tons of events.

**The observations are:**

- polling every 2 seconds brings a bit of stress to the service (~40% CPU usage during the test) and almost no stress to the MongoDB (~4%)
- listening via SSE maxes out the MongoDB (~90%), also stresses the service (which tries to use the rest of available resources), but Mongo is particularly struggling and overall the service becomes almost unresponsive.

The observation seems obvious, because when I have connected via SSE during the test, it has updated me almost instantly when new event arrived - basically SSE was hundreds of times more responsive than polling every 2 seconds.

**The question is:**

Given that the client is ultimately the subscriber (or at least I think it is given by limited knowledge), can I somehow throttle the rate of publishing messages by ReactiveMongoTemplate? Or somehow decrease the demand for new events without having to do that client-side?

I have been trying my luck with Flux buffering and cache'ing, however it caused even more stress...

**Code:**

```
// ChatRepository.java

private static final Query chatEventsQuery = new Query();

public Flux<ChatEvent> getChatEventsStream(String chatId) {
    return reactiveMongoTemplate.tail(
            chatEventsQuery,
            ChatEvent.class,
            chatId
    );
}
```

,

```
// ChatHandler.java

public Mono<ServerResponse> getChatStream(ServerRequest request) {

    String chatId = request.pathVariable(CHAT_ID_PATH_VARIABLE);
    String username = getUsername(request);

    Flux<ServerSentEvent> chatEventsStream = chatRepository
            .getChatEventsStream(chatId)
            .map(addUserSpecificPropsToChatEvent(username))
            .map(event -> ServerSentEvent.<ChatEvent>builder()
                    .event(event.getType().getEventName())
                    .data(event)
                    .build());

    log.debug("\nExposing chat stream\nchat: {}\nuser: {}", chatId, username);

    return ServerResponse.ok().body(
            chatEventsStream,
            ServerSentEvent.class
    );
}
```

,

```
// ChatRouter.java

RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(ChatHandler handler) {
    return route(GET("/api/chat/{chatId}/stream"), handler::getChatStream);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer is:**
You do it by using `Flux.buffer` method. Then the flux will send the events to the subscribers in bulks at a defined rate.

**The code I have posted had 2 major issues**

1. Given that multiple users are usually listening to one chat, I have refactored the ChatRepository to take advantage of "Hot", replayable Fluxes (now I have 1 stream per chat instead of 1 stream per user) which I store in [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/) cache.
   Additionally I am buffering them by short time intervals to avoid heavy resource usage on pushing the events to the clients on busy chats.
2. The `new Query()` I have used in the ChatRepository was redundant. I
   have looked at ReactiveMongoTemplate's code and if a non-null
   query is provided, the logic is a bit more complex. It's better to pass `null`
   to ReactiveMongoTemplate's `tail()` method instead.

**Code post-refactoring**

```
// ChatRepository.java

public Flux<List<ChatEvent>> getChatEventsStream(String chatId) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(chatStreamsCache.getIfPresent(chatId))
            .orElseGet(newCachedChatEventsStream(chatId))
            .autoConnect();
}

private Supplier<ConnectableFlux<List<ChatEvent>>> newCachedChatEventsStream(String chatId) {
    return () -> {
        ConnectableFlux<List<ChatEvent>> chatEventsStream = reactiveMongoTemplate.tail(
                null,
                ChatEvent.class,
                chatId
        ).buffer(Duration.ofMillis(chatEventsBufferInterval))
                .replay(chatEventsReplayCount);

        chatStreamsCache.put(chatId, chatEventsStream);

        return chatEventsStream;
    };
}
```

,

```
// ChatHandler.java

public Mono<ServerResponse> getChatStream(ServerRequest request) {

    String chatId = request.pathVariable(CHAT_ID_PATH_VARIABLE);
    String username = getUsername(request);

    Flux<ServerSentEvent> chatEventsStream = chatRepository
            .getChatEventsStream(chatId)
            .map(addUserSpecificPropsToChatEvents(username))
            .map(event -> ServerSentEvent.<List<ChatEvent>>builder()
                    .event(CHAT_SSE_NAME)
                    .data(event)
                    .build());

    log.debug("\nExposing chat stream\nchat: {}\nuser: {}", chatId, username);

    return ServerResponse.ok().body(
            chatEventsStream,
            ServerSentEvent.class
    );
}
```

,

After applying these changes, the service performs well even with 3000 active users (JVM uses ~50% of CPU, Mongo ~7% mostly due to lots of inserts - the streams are not that noticeable now)